# Left Outer Join Returns less rows

Tags: sql, oracle

A query with inner joins:

```
Select 
  O.ORDER_KEY, O.ORDER_SOURCE,
-------, ---
FROM 
  Table_1, Table_2, Table_3
where
  TABLE_1.SK = TABLE_2.SK AND TABLE_2.SK = TABLE_3.SK and many more;
```

The above query returns around 10000 rows.

I want to add another table but at the same time I do not want to loose orders from table_2. To achieve this, I used left_outer_join:

```
Select 
  O.ORDER_KEY, NVL(O.ORDER_SOURCE, WROA.ORDER_SOURCE) AS ORDER_SOURCE,
-------, ---
FROM 
  Table_1, Table_2, Table_3, Table_4
where
  TABLE_1.SK = TABLE_2.SK AND TABLE_2.SK = TABLE_3.SK AND
  TABLE_2.ORDER = TABLE_4.ORDER(+);
```

The above query returns 200 rows.

Why is it not returning 10000 rows? Did I miss something? How is adding one more condition with left outer join effecting that many rows?

Comment: There are joins in old syntax but this query is nonsense. What is `TABLE_2_ORDER`? There is no such table. And what is `and many more;`? which can have a lot of `(+) First I'd recommend to rewirte to proper join syntax. Then post whole query to analyse. This is too few to say anything

Comment: pretty sure that's a right join.  include all table4_order records and only those that match in table_2_order.

Comment: "=" is considered as inner join and adding "(+)" at the end is left outer join. Right?

Comment: @xQbert - does the first example on the [page](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/network/2002/10/01/whatsinacondition.html) explain what OP is trying to do. It does say, thats a left outer join

Comment: And this is why I like the ANSI 92 standards :P agreed that is th left join the (+) goes on the side that doesn't contain all records.

Comment: @Purvisingla Do you have other limits on table_4 in the where clause which would cause the NULL records to be excluded?  e.g. `table_4.FieldX = 'somevalue'`

Comment: @Kacper I am sorry, cannot write the exact query here. I will try to be more specific in future. By "Many more" I mean "="  inner joins and it only has one (+) left outer join.

Comment: @xQbert Table_4 has only one condition in the where clause which I mentioned above in the query (left outer join one).

Comment: @PurviSingla In table `TABLE_2` all 10000 lines have data in `ORDER` column ?

Comment: @SudiptaMondal Hey, sorry for being unclear. 10000 is the total rows returned by the first query after applying inner joins. Its not the case where I have 10000 rows of data in TABLE_2.

Comment: @PurviSingla if you add `table_2.order` in your `select clause` for the first query with 3 tables, does all 10000 records have data in it ?

Comment: @SudiptaMondal Though its redundant value, but yes it has value for table_2.order. If I apply left outer join, it basically removed duplicate rows and return only the unique ones. By only concern is, why is it not returning duplicates ones. Trying to dig in more as it is really a big query.

Comment: @SudiptaMondal Got it, there is one table which wasn't used in the where clause so it was doing Cartesian product internally with all the data.

Comment: @PurviSingla that explains your redundant data.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of where clause you have defined. New table you are adding, column from this table is part of where clause? If yes then use inline view for that column to see if it gives you correct result.

Comment: Yeah, I added table_4  and this condition TABLE_2.ORDER = TABLE_4.ORDER(+)  is the only condition I added in the original query in where clause. I will try inline view. Thank you so much.

Comment: If inline view works for you then you can opt for ANSI join what xQbert mentioned in his answer, it will give elegant look to your query and its easier to maintain as well. I dont think so performance will be hamper but its always good to go for ANSI join syntax.

Comment: I will surely try inline view. Its a very big query. Will take time to convert it. :D

Answer (score 0):

This is what I mean by ANSI 92...

```
SELECT O.ORDER_KEY, NVL(O.ORDER_SOURCE, WROA.ORDER_SOURCE) AS ORDER_SOURCE, ...
FROM  Table_1
INNER JOIN Table_2
  ON TABLE_1.SK = TABLE_2.SK 
INNER JOIN Table_3
  ON TABLE_2.SK = TABLE_3.SK AND
LEFT JOIN Table_4
  ON TABLE_2.ORDER = TABLE_4.ORDER
WHERE ...
```

Comment: Yeah, I understood and will try this way. Thank you so much.